# I cannot put TextView on the right side of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm kind of new in Android App develop, there is my problem, I created a scrollview, inside scrollview I have LinearLayout. The problem is in the LinearLayout I cannot put the textview beside to the ImageView, really stuck here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_item_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.example.daniw.traekle.ItemDetail">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ISBN"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="ISBN"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_book"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="This is bookInfo"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sellerInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Seller INFO"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is what happened

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XML Code might help you...
I have set `imageView_seller` at leftside of `tv_sellerInfo`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_item_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ISBN"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="ISBN"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_book"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="This is bookInfo"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_seller"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sellerInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Seller INFO"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really work. Finally i can move on.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the orientation of your `LinearLayout` is `vertical` (one view below the other), try to change to `horizontal` or change of `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and add the constraints that you want.

Answer (score 0):

add a linearlayout where you want to put textview right of image view. set the orientation of this linearlayout is hrizontal then put imageview and then textview in this linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

do this -

android:orientation="horizontal"

like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_item_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.example.daniw.traekle.ItemDetail">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ISBN"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="ISBN"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_book"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bookInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="This is bookInfo"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sellerInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_seller"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Seller INFO"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```